# Конфигурация H2

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

Пытаюсь сделать простое web приложение на spring boot + hibernate + H2

application.properties

```
# Database
db.driver=Org.H2.Driver
db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS phonecall;
db.username=sa
db.password=

#Hibernate
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
entitymanager.packagesToScan=com.antoncharov.statistics
```

DBConfiguration.java

```
package com.antoncharov.statistics.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBConfiguration {
    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String DRIVER;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String PASSWORD;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String URL;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String USERNAME;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String DIALECT;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String SHOW_SQL;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String HBM2DDL_AUTO;

    @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
    private String PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", DIALECT);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", SHOW_SQL);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HBM2DDL_AUTO);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

При запуске вылетает исключение

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Org.H2.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:127) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
```

Почему то не находит драйвер для H2. Как по уму сконфигурировать подключение к H2 без xml?

Comment: в `Spring Boot` не нужны конфигурации для датасоурса - они уже все есть. Вы просто указываете данные для подключения в `application.properties`.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database

Comment: Вообще, уже верно указали, для того чтобы в spring boot подключится к inmemory h2 database необходимо просто указать зависимость (dependency). А вот не находит класс `Org.H2.Driver`, потому что вы не верно указали пакет, нужно `org.h2.Driver`

Answer (score 0):

С такими настройками точно работает -

```
spring.datasource.platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```